# Laravel: Change Guard in ForgotPasswordController

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

I used the `php artisan make:auth` feature to have a quick build in Reset-Password and Forget-Password option.

When I go to "Forget-Password" and enter the email of an registered user, I get a message that the email is not found. This happend since I have changed my default guard.

How can I fix this? I want to use `ForgotEmailController` for the non-default guard, which is related to a specific model. I think that the Controller is not searching the email in the correct DB from the specific guard. But there is no `default guard()` method to overwrite in `ForgotEmailController` as in `ResetPasswordController`.

Comment: I believe it is inheriting the guard from the Controller.php AuthorizeRequests. i think you can just redefine your method in the controller where you need it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since I have not used the default model I needed to use a custom broker:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password;

class ForgotPasswordController extends Controller
{
  // ...

  // Password Broker for Seller Model
  public function broker()
  {
       return Password::broker('dogs');
  }
}
```

The broker class "dogs" has do be defined in `config/auth.php`

```
'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
        'dogs' => [
            'provider' => 'dogs',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],


'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],

    'dogs' =>[
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Dogs::class,
    ],

    // 'users' => [
    //     'driver' => 'database',
    //     'table' => 'users',
    // ],
],
```